# Como eu faço o tratamento direto na model do Laravel tanto set como get?

Tags: laravel, replace

Estou trabalhando em um banco de dados já povoado e estou precisando fazer a substituição de `,` por `.` e de `/` por `-` sem precisar de recorrer ao frontend somente na model.

Comment: Você poderia montar um exemplo minimo? Porque são essas alterações? Me relate mais sobre esse banco legado

Comment: para isso, você pode utilizar os **Mutators**. Segue o link da documentação:
[Eloquent: Mutators](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators)

Comment: Muito  Odilon Garcez o  Mutators resouleu